# Installing PhoneGap Developer App on a virtual device

Tags: android, phonegap

I cannot find PhoneGap Developer App on any virtual device (I checked on standard Android Studio virtual device and Genymotion), its just not listed if I search for it in Google Play, I can only see PhoneGap Demo App. I know I can test from browser on virtual android, but I am finding some plugins not working correctly in browser (like navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition works fine in PhoneGap Deveoper App but complains about non secure cinnection when run in browser (http://PhoneGapDesktop:3000)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to download PhoneGap Developer App apk to your PC and drag it to emulator.

It will automatically install the desired app to your emulator.

*Please note that since this is obviously for educational purpouse, you should first understand and legally evaluate the terms of use of PhoneGap Developer App.*